# Windows Storage Spaces can't set "Storage Space Size"

Tags: windows, powershell, windows-10, storage

## Update

In the end, I moved my files to the 2 new 8TB drives and then I created a new 2-way mirrored storage pool using the 4 original drives. I then added my files back to the new pool and then added the 2 new drives to the pool.

### I had a few issues along the way:

1. When I created the new pool, ReFS is no longer an option for the file system.

   Basically Microsoft has removed the ability to create ReFS partitions from Windows 10 Home and Pro. This is complete B.S. they shouldn't be able to remove features from a product that you purchased, possibly for the reason of it having that feature.
2. I was unable to add the 2 new 8TB HDDs to my new 2-way mirrored pool.

   When I tried to do so, I was met with an error dialog stating that the request is not supported.

   [image: drive adding error]

As it turns out, drives that were once part of a storage spaces pool seem to have some left-over data on them which doesn't allow them to be added to a new pool.

Luckily, I found others asking about this and [there was a solution](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_10-files-winpc/storage-spaces-win-10-cant-add-new-drive-error/eca10bd6-5564-45a0-9649-d00619a68fe6?auth=1). Basically, you have to run PowerShell as an Admin user and then run the command to list all physical disks:

```
Get-PhysicalDisk | ft FriendlyName, SerialNumber, UniqueId -auto
```

Then run the command to reset the "bad" drive(s):

```
Reset-PhysicalDisk -UniqueId "90dbac25-f5dd-ea00-8e51-4ca8414aa21f"
```

Once I did this, I was able to add my 2 new drives to the new pool and I was good to go.

---

I've been using Windows Storage Spaces for just over a year now to house my media collection on Windows 10. I started with 2 8TB drives, then added 2 more and now I've added 2 more.

However, this time when I added the 2 latest drives I tried to change my "Storage Space Size (maximum)", but any value that I put in there just shows an error message below stating that that's an invalid size.
The default value in that box is 63TB, but when I look at my storage space drive in windows explorer, it only shows 14TB.

Are there any command-line (powershell) commands which I can use to either "repair" it or force it to accept a new "maximum" size?
I've read that you can't make that "Storage Space Size" smaller, but is there some solution to my problem?

Please don't give any answers along the lines of "Don't use Storage Spaces". That just isn't constructive and doesn't help to solve my issue.

### PS

I cannot delete my pool/storage space since I have nowhere to put my files temporarily.

Answer (score 1):

In checking TechNet here: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj851254(v=wps.630).aspx looks like the `Repair-SpacesConfiguration` cmdlet might be what you want.

The long description for it says it does the following:

Repair-SpacesConfiguration
Windows Server 2012 R2 and Windows 8.1
Repair-SpacesConfiguration
Repairs unhealthy resources associated with a Storage Spaces storage pool.
Syntax

Repair-SpacesConfiguration [ ]

Detailed Description
The Repair-SpacesConfiguration cmdlet repairs unhealthy Storage Spaces resources. It performs the following operations:

Enumerate storage pools that are read-only and offer to recover them
Enumerate storage spaces that are set for manual attachment, and attach them
Enumerate and repair any unhealthy storage spaces
Enumerate and display any unhealthy physical disks

Comment: Thanks a lot, I'll give that a try once mine finishes optimizing :(

Comment: Unfortunately, the Repair-SpacesConfiguraton isn't present in Windows 10.

Comment: I'd have to do some reading and see what else would be possible, haven't worked with that feature before. Will take a look and let you know if I find anything

Comment: Thanks a lot @trebleCode, I appreciate your time.
But in the end, I just removed my 2 new 8TB drives from the array and I'm currently transferred the contents of my 16TB redundant array to the 2 of them.
Next I'll re-create the array using the soon to be empty 4 8TB drives but I'll set the maximum size to the max (63TB) right away transfer all of the files back to the new redundant array and add the 2 new 8TB drives back to the array.

It's a PITA, but for now I don't want to move my PLEX server over to Unraid or FreeNAS.

Comment: I've found that most of what I can find on Storage Spaces on line pertains to Windows 8.1 and is no longer relevant in Windows 10 :(